# Correlated binomial distribution

Tags: correlation, binomial-distribution

I have a series of trials such that $X_i$ takes only binary outcome. There are in total $N$ trials. Denote, $X=X_1+X_2+\ldots +X_N$. For all $i$ $P(X_i=0)=p=1-P(X_i=1)$.

However there is correlation, between successive trials, ie $P(X_i|X_{i-1}) \neq P(X_i)$. Given $P(X_i=a|X_{i-1}=b)$, how can I find the distributions for $P(X=n)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably it is better to name it 'dependence' rather than ' correlation'?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: If $P(X_i|X_{i-1}) \neq P(X_i)$, shouldn't you have $\forall_i P(X_i=0)=p_\color{red}{i}=1-P(X_i=1)$?

Comment: @gung How would that follow?  It's perfectly possible for all $P(X_i=0)$ to be equal without being independent.  (Although there don't seem to be many interesting ways in which that would happen...)

Comment: @whuber, perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. If the probability that a given realization, $x_i$, takes a given value, say $0$, depends on the prior realization, then it seems to me we need to state that each $x_i$ has a potentially different probability, $p_i$. If the statement is meant to refer to the marginal probability as constant for all, then I might think we'd write, $P(X = 0) = p = 1- P(X = 1)$ (ie, w/o $i$'s).

Comment: @gung That would be a good thing to assume, but it's not necessary.  For instance, in the stochastic process $X_i=U$ for all $i$ and $U\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1-p)$ the $X_i$ are not independent but nevertheless each has $\Pr(X_i=0)=p$.

Comment: Hmmm, OK then. Shall I delete these comments, @whuber? (Are they just a distraction here?)

Comment: @gung I think they're fine, because they suggest the question really ought not be so restrictive and that it should be generalized as you indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire probability distribution for X, namely P(X = i) for all values of i from 0 to N, can be obtained using a discrete-time (time-inhomogeneous) Markov Chain having $2N + 2$ states.

The states are:

- "Initial state of 0 trials having been conducted"
- For each i from  0 to N-1, there is a state for "i trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 0"
- For each i from 0 to N-1, there is a state for "i trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 1"
- There is a single state for "N trials have had value 1"

The one-step transition matrix M is formed in the obvious fashion for the transitions between the states, based on the data you say is available.

The Markov Chain is started in the initial state of 0 trials having been conducted, and is run for N steps.  The first row of $M^N$ contains the probabilities of being in the various states after N trials.

For each i from 0 to N-1, P(X = i) = sum of the entries in the first row of $M^N$ for the states "i trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 0" and "i trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 1".

P(X = N) = entry in the first row of $M^N$ for the state "N trials have had value 1"

Here is a sample formulation and results:
Let N = 3, so there are 8 states, which I have ordered:

- "Initial state of 0 trials having been conducted"
- "0 trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 0"
- "0 trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 1"
- "1 trial has had value 1, with most recent trial being 0"
- "1 trial has had value 1, with most recent trial being 1"
- "2 trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 0"
- "2 trials have had value 1, with most recent trial being 1"
- "3 trials have had value 1"

In this example,let

- p = 0.5
- P(trial has same value as previous trial)  = d
- P(trial has different value than previous trial) = 1-d

A value of d = 0.5 corresponds to independent (binomial) trials, d = 1 corresponds to perfectly correlated trials, and d = 0 corresponds to perfectly anti-correlated (i.e., flip-flopping) trials.

Here is the single step transition matrix M for d = 0.8.

```
 0    0.5000         0         0    0.5000         0         0         0
 0    0.8000         0         0    0.2000         0         0         0
 0    0.2000         0         0    0.8000         0         0         0
 0         0         0    0.8000         0         0    0.2000         0
 0         0         0    0.2000         0         0    0.8000         0
 0         0         0         0         0    0.8000         0    0.2000
 0         0         0         0         0    0.2000         0    0.8000
 0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
```

Here are the resulting probability distributions for X for values of d from 0 to 1 in 0.1 increments.  All the results make perfect sense to me.

```
   d      P(X=0)    P(X=1)    P(X=2)    P(X=3)

0.0000         0    0.5000    0.5000         0
0.1000    0.0050    0.4950    0.4950    0.0050
0.2000    0.0200    0.4800    0.4800    0.0200
0.3000    0.0450    0.4550    0.4550    0.0450
0.4000    0.0800    0.4200    0.4200    0.0800
0.5000    0.1250    0.3750    0.3750    0.1250
0.6000    0.1800    0.3200    0.3200    0.1800
0.7000    0.2450    0.2550    0.2550    0.2450
0.8000    0.3200    0.1800    0.1800    0.3200
0.9000    0.4050    0.0950    0.0950    0.4050
1.0000    0.5000         0         0    0.5000
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion is brilliant!! Do you happen to know whether one can get analytical results for the distribution of P(X=n)? How about in the case of N tends to infinity? Many thanks

Comment: I consider these to be analytical results, as simple or simpler than many godawful summations which you might see.. I am not saying there are not "simpler" analytical results.